# Why is scrapy returning None for the "Title" item?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to crawl https://www.jobs.ch/de/stellenangebote/administration-hr-consulting-ceo/, where I am currently stuck because scrapy returns None for the "Title" item, which is the job name. The css selector works fine in the shell and the other items work also. I've tried to alter the selector or add delays, but nothing seems to work. Has anybody an idea? Code below.

```
import scrapy
from jobscraping.items import JobscrapingItem


class GetdataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'getdata2'
    start_urls = ['https://www.jobs.ch/de/stellenangebote/administration-hr-consulting-ceo/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for add in response.css('div.sc-AxiKw.VacancySerpItem__ShadowBox-qr45cp-0.hqhfbd'):
            item = JobscrapingItem()
            addpage = response.urljoin(add.css('div.sc-AxiKw.VacancySerpItem__ShadowBox-qr45cp-0.hqhfbd a::attr(href)').get())
            item['link'] = addpage


            request = scrapy.Request(addpage, callback=self.get_addinfos)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def get_addinfos(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['Title'] = response.css('.sc-AxhUy.Text__h2-jiiyzm-1.eBKnmN.sc-fzqNJr.Text__span-jiiyzm-8.Text-jiiyzm-9.iNTZsv::text').get()
        item['Company'] = response.css('span.sc-fzqNJr.Text__span-jiiyzm-8.kGLBca.sc-fzqNJr.Text__span-jiiyzm-8.Text-jiiyzm-9.kjfvVS::text').get()
        item['Location'] = response.css('span.sc-fzqNJr.Text__span-jiiyzm-8.kGLBca.sc-fzqNJr.Text__span-jiiyzm-8.Text-jiiyzm-9.WBPTt::text').getall()
        yield item
```

This is the items.py file:

```
import scrapy


class JobscrapingItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    link = scrapy.Field()
    Title = scrapy.Field()
    Company = scrapy.Field()
    Location = scrapy.Field()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a lot more complicated css selector. Remember you don't always have to use classes or id. Yuo can use other attributes like in this case `data-cy="vacancy-title"` seems to be perfect.

`item['Title'] = response.css('h1[data-cy="vacancy-title"]::text').get()`

should work. It is simple and easy to debug and change later if something goes wrong.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about the attribute selector.

Comment: You can try the same thing for other selectors too. I didn't bother checking others but you can definitely simplify them.